# Everything works in Unity but not on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gzip

I created a server/client game in visual studio. The apps connect over TCP. After everything worked as intended i created the client app in Unity. When i play the game in Unity application everything is ok (The client communicates with server etc). When i export the game in Windows the game is ok. The problem is when i export it to an Android (apk) the game on the device does not communicate with server.

Using Debugger i found the first problem (not sure if there are more) is when i am trying to compress and split the package to be send. I split each package at 1024 and rejoin them at the recipient.

The pack class:

```
public class MessageBoxPack
    {
        private List<MessageBox> msgBoxContainer;
        private byte[] msgByte { get; set; }
        private MessageBox msgBox;
        private int bufferSize;

        public List<MessageBox> PrepareMsgBoxList(MessageSlip msg, int _bufferSize)
        {                
            msgBoxContainer = new List<MessageBox>();
            bufferSize = _bufferSize;
            ConvertMessageToBytes(msg);
            return msgBoxContainer;
        }

        private void ConvertMessageToBytes(MessageSlip msg)
        {
            BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    f.Serialize(gZip, msg);
                }
                byte[] b = ms.ToArray();
                int TotalLength = b.Length;
                int currentPosition = 0;
                int writeLength = bufferSize;
                while (currentPosition < TotalLength)
                {
                    msgBox = new MessageBox();
                    msgBox.CallBackID = msg.CallBackID;
                    if (currentPosition + bufferSize > TotalLength)
                        writeLength = TotalLength - currentPosition;
                    msgBox.MessageBytes = new byte[writeLength];
                    Array.Copy(b, currentPosition, msgBox.MessageBytes, 0, writeLength);
                    msgBox.currentPossition = currentPosition;
                    msgBox.byteLength = TotalLength;
                    currentPosition += writeLength;
                    msgBoxContainer.Add(msgBox);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And the unpack class:

```
public class MessageBoxUnpack
    {

        public MessageSlip UnpackMsgBoxList(List<MessageBox> msgBoxList, int _bufferSize)
        {
            MessageSlip msg = new MessageSlip();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                foreach (MessageBox msgBox in msgBoxList)
                {
                    //ms.Position = (int)msgBox.currentPossition;
                    ms.Write(msgBox.MessageBytes, 0, msgBox.MessageBytes.Length);

                }
                int i = (int)ms.Length;
                BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                //ms.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                //msg = f.Deserialize(ms) as MessageSlip;
                using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    msg = f.Deserialize(gZip) as MessageSlip;
                }

            }
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

The Error i receive is at

```
using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
```

Can you explain to me where is the problem, how to correct it and let me know if the method i am using to pack, unpack and split is ok.

Comment: Soo, you're getting an error but what does that error say?

Comment: Not sure what the error was. It just stopped running the script and i guess continue to the next update. I am not sure where to find the error message but i found a solution. I was using System.IO.Compression which i found out is not supported in 3.5. Now i am using DoNetZip and it works as intended.

Comment: @Gizazas check [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/any-tips-for-debugging-android.70197/) forum post out to learn how to get log from android. Then paste the log in your post.